# Data not binding in route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I am stuck in the last part of this Codecademy AngularJs project

I have used routing and the routing works (it changes the view when clicked), but doesn't show data binding. I have checked **index.html** so I don't think there's a mistake there. Could you please check it? Here is the code:

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('CalendarApp', ['ngRoute'])
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider .when('/', {
    controller: 'DayController',
    templateUrl: 'views/day.html'
  }).when('/:id',{
    controller: 'EventController',
    templateUrl: 'views/event.html'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
}]);
```

**events.js** (Service)

```
app.factory('events', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/events-api/events.json').success(function(data) {
    return data;
  }).error(function(err) {
    return err;
  });
}]);
```

**EventController.js**

```
app.controller('EventController', ['$scope', 'events', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams, events) {
  $scope.eventId = $routeParams.id;
  events.success(function(data) {
    $scope.event = data.events;
  });
}]);
```

**event.html** (view)

```
<div class="event-detail">
  <h2 class="event-name">{{event[eventId].name}}</h2>
</div>
```

And here's the short format of **events.json** whose data I'm trying to get:

```
{
  "date": 1421384400000,
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "Casual Friday",
      "from": 1421384400000,
      "to": 1421470800000,
      "where": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "Taco Time",
      "from": 1421431200000,
      "to": 1421438400000,
      "where": "Brooklyn Taco Co. 120 Essex Street New York, NY 10002"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is no `id` in the data, so what are you trying to match it to in the url?

Comment: @charlietfl I think `id` is just a name I can use to get the index? I am then using the index to get the information I need in EventController?

Comment: well that wouldn't be normal since index will change in dynamic data but would work for now with your static data

Comment: So what should I do to get it to work? Do you need the code for my DayController and days.html view?

Comment: how many items do you have? Think database where you would give every row a unique identifier like `id`.  If you don't have many just add one. Then iterate the array to find the match

Comment: The items are in the array of events.json. I deleted most of the items in the code above because I just wanted to show the format of events.json. Does that help?

Comment: @charlietfl Here's the code to DayController.js just in case:

`app.controller('DayController', ['$scope', 'events', function($scope, events) {
  events.success(function(data) {
    $scope.day = data;
  });
}]);`

Comment: try this just for fun ... `$scope.event = data.events[+$routeParams.id]`;  zero will be first event

Comment: That didn't work... :/

Answer (score 0):

**events.js**
try returning promise, but load it only once;

```
app.factory('events', ['$http', function($http) {
    var promise = $http.get('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp4/events-api/events.json');
    return {
        getEvents : function(){ return promise; }
    }
}]);
```

Now if you console.log it you should recieve Promise object in your controller.

**EventController.js**

```
app.controller('EventController', ['$scope', 'events','$routeParams', function($scope, events, $routeParams) {

    // code in regards to itemId etc.

    events.getEvents().then(function(d){
        $scope.event = d.data.events; 
    });

}]);
```

(considering rest of the functionality works as you mentioned)
Let me know if it works